# Capistrano error: Error validating server certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, deployment

When I tried to deploy my Ruby on Rails application using Capistrano, I received the following error:

```
cap deploy

* executing `deploy'
* executing `deploy:update'
** transaction: start
* executing `deploy:update_code'
executing locally: "svn info https://digitalsleep.svn.beanstalkapp.com/centralbank/  -rHEAD"
svn: /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0)
svn: /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libpq.so.5)
* executing "svn checkout -q  -r66 https://digitalsleep.svn.beanstalkapp.com/centralbank/ /home/monkeyg/centralbank/releases/20091203102124 && (echo 66 > /home/monkeyg/centralbank/releases/20091203102124/REVISION)"
    servers: ["67.23.24.230"]

    [67.23.24.230] executing command

** [67.23.24.230 :: err] Error validating server certificate for 'https://digitalsleep.svn.beanstalkapp.com:443':

** - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
** fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!

** Certificate information:
** - Hostname: *.svn.beanstalkapp.com
** - Valid: from Thu, 05 Mar 2009 15:23:20 GMT until Wed, 14 Apr 2010 03:34:53 GMT
** - Issuer: 07969287, http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository, GoDaddy.com, Inc., Scottsdale, Arizona, US
** - Fingerprint: b0:3b:ea:3a:72:2c:87:30:75:d3:7d:2b:01:4b:ec:d6:45:38:8f:25
** (R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?

** [67.23.24.230 :: err] Authentication realm: <https://digitalsleep.svn.beanstalkapp.com:443> SVN
** Password for 'root':

** [67.23.24.230 :: err] Authentication realm: <https://digitalsleep.svn.beanstalkapp.com:443> SVN
** Username:
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running this from the command line:

```
svn info https://digitalsleep.svn.beanstalkapp.com/centralbank/  -rHEAD
```

Then try to run it from capistrano.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to connect with SSL. And you've never done that before on that host.

You must do a manual checkout once first and permanently accept the SSL certificate.
Then your host will be able to checkout your svn repository.